# Configure postfix to strictly check for syntax errors

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am adding email support to my application. I am using postfix to send email by calling the `sendmail` compatibility interface and writing to standard input.

This works great but occasionally emails are not accepted by some mail servers. I do not have access to those mail servers so I cannot check the logs to see why. All I know is the connection is just terminated while sending the email message.

I assume this is because I am using a feature that postfix supports but other (older) mail servers do not support. For example, I have had issues with 8 bit characters in SMTP headers that postfix accepted but some mail servers choked on.

To diagnose the cause, I want to configure postfix to allow only a basic set of features and to strictly check the emails I am sending. Hopefully postfix will then give an indication on what is wrong with the email and I can fix that in my application.

However I have no experience with configuring postfix. I have checked the documentation but there a gazillion options and is hard to determine what to configure, and how.

Can someone provide any pointers, or alternative ways to investigate the issue?

Comment: Are the [`strict_*`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#strict_7bit_headers) options what you're looking for?

Comment: @Ginnungagap These look like useful options to start with.